# TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pytorch

```py
class DeConv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channel, out_channel, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation):
        super().__init__()

        self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channel, out_channel, kernel_size=kernel_size, \
                              stride=stride, padding=padding, dilation=dilation)


    def forward(self, x):

        output = self.up(x)
        output = self.conv(output)

        return output

class EncoderDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_net, n_class):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_class = n_class
        self.pretrained_net = pretrained_net
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        self.deconv1 = DeConv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, dilation=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)

        self.deconv2 = DeConv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, dilation=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)

        self.deconv3 = DeConv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, dilation=1)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)

        self.deconv4 = DeConv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, dilation=1)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)

        self.classifier = nn.Conv2d(64, n_class, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):

        output=self.pretrained_net.layers(x)


        output=self.relu(self.deconv1(output))
        output=self.bn1(output)


        output=self.relu(self.deconv2(output))
        output=self.bn2(output)


        output=self.relu(self.deconv3(output))
        output=self.bn3(output)


        output=self.relu(self.deconv4(output))
        output=self.bn4(output)


        output=self.classifier(output)



        return output
```

this is my code and I don't know why the type error exist . Does somebody know how to fix these problems?

Comment: class is to be added in block

Comment: Can you please format the question and also add the error output with some more details.

Comment: I found this because I'm getting the same error with PyTorch and am not able to figure out why. I agree with @nsidn98 that you should add more information about the error you are getting, namely the full traceback.

Comment: In my case, I get this error when `forward()` is called internally after I call `model(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a class, and define a function with `self` args within the class, self is autofilled with the class.Ex:

```py
class item():# create a random class
 self.var = 0
 def fun(self,x):
  self.var +=x
n = item()
```

And you can try add:

```
n.fun(3)
print(n.var)
```

returns `3`

`self` argument is autofilled with class itself

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used `transformers.Trainer.train()` to train my `model`. And then I used `predict_scores = model(predict_dataset)` to get the prediction result.  But I got the same error as "forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given...".

Then I changed to `predict_scores = trainer.predict(predict_dataset)`, then I got the correct result. Hope this is helpful to others. I am a newbie to PyTorch.